# Flash Error #1063: Argument count mismatch

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

```
ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on scripts::GamePlay(). Expected 1, got 0.
    at flash.display::Sprite/constructChildren()
    at flash.display::Sprite()
    at flash.display::MovieClip()
```

I have some of these errors when I compile and I know the solution.

```
public function GamePlay(stageRef:Stage)
        {
            this.stageRef = stageRef;
            player = new Player(stageRef);

            waitTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, WaitTimer, false, 0, true);
            waitTimer.start();

            player.addEventListener(Event.REMOVED_FROM_STAGE, PlayerRemoved, false, 0, true);
        }
```

In the constructor I must add stageRef:Stage = null this will solve the error, but if I do that all my timers think the stage is null or something is null, like so.

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at scripts::GamePlay/WaitTimer()[C:\Users\Noodles\Documents\Flash Projects\BlockDrop\scripts\GamePlay.as:71]
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEventFunction()
    at flash.events::EventDispatcher/dispatchEvent()
    at flash.utils::Timer/tick()
```

What can I do to fix this error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you creating this object in the constructor of your main application's document class? If so, you'll run into this issue even if the rest of your code is perfect because of the way Flash Player works.

Basically, "Stage" is null until your main application is added to the stage. This is a quick shortcut to lots of unusual behavior and hard-to-trace bugs. A very common solution is to minimize the code in your document class's constructor. Instead of putting your init logic in your constructor, your constructor just adds an event listener for Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, and your logic goes into your handler. It would look something like this:

```
protected var gamePlay:GamePlay;

public function MyConstructor():void {
     this.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedHandler, false, 0, true);
}

protected function addedHandler(e:Event):void {
     this.removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, addedHandler);
     gamePlay = new GamePlay(this.stage);
}
```

Let me know if that solves your problem, it's possible I'm not entirely understanding what's going on - but regardless, if you're having issues where stage is null when it shouldn't be this is usually the cause.

Comment: I'm not creating the object in the main constructor class.  It's created in a menu class and ran from there.  From the main class the stage is passed into a menu class and I think that is where the problem is coming from.  I'm going to attempt running it from the main class and see what happens.

Comment: OK, the same principle applies. the variable "stage" in the constructor of your document class will be null. If you pass the reference to that variable before the application's "ADDED_TO_STAGE" event fires then you're just passing a null object, and when it DOES get added to stage and the stage variable gets populated your other classes have no way of knowing that the null object is out of date.

Comment: I'm still getting the timer error.  I tried making an if statment with if(stage) init(); else addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, Init); and I get "not compile-time event" or something error.

Comment: Well, that error can mean almost anything but generally speaking it suggests you have a typo somewhere.

I wouldn't necessarily worry about the whole if(stage) thing, I would just add your event listener. It looks like at least in the comment you've just made that your function is called init() but that in your addEventListener() you're passing Init - AS3 is case sensitive, so maybe that's it?

Comment: Still not working at all, would you know the consequence of having those errors?  It doesn't seem to hinder my game at all, or does anything noticeable.  I mean the 1063 error in the beginning of the question.

Comment: Well, at its most basic what that means is that when you create a GamePlay object it's expecting you to pass something (presumably a reference to stage) to the GamePlay object's constructor. However, the error means that you're attempting to use the constructor without actually passing anything at all - new GamePlay(stage) vs new GamePlay(). GamePlay expects an object, so that initial error tells me that somewhere you're just calling "GamePlay()" without passing anything.

Comment: I see, the problem is I am passing the stage into it.  Flash just doesn't see it.  So I don't really know what I can do at this point.

Comment: Well, you shouldn't be getting that error actually even if you're passing a null reference to stage. That first error in your post above is explicitly saying "Hey you forgot to pass a reference!"

Comment: I guess that would explain why I can't find any answers to my problem.  Somewhere in the code the stage becomes null, but not null which is ridiculous.  I've decided to remake my entire game, hopefully I cant avoid that again.

Comment: I strongly recommend using a game framework, something like Flixel or PushButtonEngine. It'll take a little bit of time to get up to speed, but these frameworks abstract away EVERYTHING for you so your game will perform better and you'll more control over stuff like this. Google 'em!

Answer (score 2):

When you call GamePlay, specify a Stage parameter.

```
function fn() //calling function
{
 GamePlay(Stage); //pass Stage to the GamePlay function.
}
```